# Create A Reminder Based On The Current Day

Tags: date, vb6

I am making a DTR, and on the Form_Load of this DTR, I want it to check for the current day date. When it reaches the 13th, 14th, 15th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th, or 30th day of the month, what I would want it to do is for it to pop-up a msgbox reminding the owner of its employee's salary. However, when I run my code, even if it does not match the day I want it to msgbox, it still message box. Example, if the current day is the 3rd of the month, it still pops up a msgbox. Here is my code. I did not use timer.

```
    Dim strDate As Integer
    If strDate = Format(Now, "d") = 13 Or 14 Or 15 Or 27 Or 28 Or 29 Or 30 Then
           'DatePart("d", Now)
             If MsgBox("Alert Edwin Jay Sandoval or Maria Consuelo regarding your salary!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Salary") = vbOK Then
          MsgBox "Alert Edwin Jay Sandoval or Maria Consuelo regarding your salary!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Salary"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You're actually going to `MsgBox` them twice there.  The nested if statement in your code is unnecessary, just keep the `MsgBox` statement.

Comment: Each person will be notified every one of those days, so if they get paid on the 13th then they'll also get reminders every other day mentioned...  Perhaps you need to break this up slightly to also include some kind of more specific check.  What are the rules of payment?  Is it fortnightly?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `Format` function to get date components. `Format` is used to return a formatted *string* of the specified date. VB is doing you a favor by casting the string to an integer for your comparison. Use VB's `Day()`, `Month()`, or `Year()` functions to extract date components instead.

```
Dim intDay As Integer
intDay = Day(Date)

Select Case intDay
    Case 13 To 15, 26 To 30
        ' Match
    Case Else
        ' No Match
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently comparing the day just to 13, and the other terms are in your `OR` statement.

You'll need to do something like:

```
If (Format(Now, "d") = 13) Or (Format(Now, "d") = 14) _
Or (Format(Now, "d") = 15) Or (Format(Now, "d") = 27) _
Or (Format(Now, "d") = 28) Or (Format(Now, "d") = 29) _
Or (Format(Now, "d") = 30) Then
...
```

You should probably pull the day number out to a variable first though.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code. It is still doing the same(popping up msgbox even if the conditions are not met)

Here is my new code: 
Dim strDate As Integer
   Const d1 = 14
   Const d2 = 15
   Const d3 = 28
   Const d4 = 29
   Const d5 = 30
   If strDate = (Format(Now, "d") = d1) Or (Format(Now, "d") = d2) _
Or (Format(Now, "d") = d3) Or (Format(Now, "d") = d4) _
Or (Format(Now, "d") = d5) Then
MsgBox "Alert Edwin Jay Sandoval or Maria Consuelo regarding your salary!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Salary"
End If

Comment: I see the problem.  The comparison included "strDate".  I've edited my response.

Comment: found the answer. strDate = Format(Now, "d")
If strDate = 13 Or strDate = 14  then blah blah..

Anyways, thank you so much for the help. how do i close this thread?

Comment: Yes, my response is equivalent to that :)  To close the thread, just accept my answer I suppose.